# How to align contents of table cell to bottom?

Tags: tables, alignment

I've looked at a few answers about aligning the contents of table cells vertically. In the MWE I provide, there are 4 tables within the columns of another table. The tables are of different sizes and I'd like them all aligned along the bottom of their cell.

[image]

So the table in the first column should be aligned to the bottom of the outer table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][-3pt]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.5ex]\node[#1](#2){};}

\tikzset{brace/.style={decorate, decoration={brace}},
 brace mirrored/.style={decorate, decoration={brace,mirror}},
}

\newcounter{brace}
\setcounter{brace}{0}
\newcommand{\drawbrace}[3][brace]{%
 \refstepcounter{brace}
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[#1] (#2.center)--(#3.center)node[pos=0.5, name=brace-\thebrace]{};
}

\newcounter{arrow}
\setcounter{arrow}{0}
\newcommand{\drawcurvedarrow}[3][]{%
 \refstepcounter{arrow}
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw (#2.center)edge[#1]node[coordinate,pos=0.5, name=arrow-\thearrow]{}(#3.center);
}

\newcommand{\annote}[3][]{%
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[#1] at (#2) {#3};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \begin{tabular}{ | l |}
    $3 \times fact(2)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.62em]{d} \\ \hline
    $4 \times fact(3)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.6em]{f}\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 &  
 \begin{tabular}{ | l |}
    $2 \times fact(1)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.62em]{1} \\ \hline
    $3 \times fact(2)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.6em]{2} \\ \hline
    $4 \times fact(3)$\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 &  
 \begin{tabular}{ | l |}
    $1 \times fact(0)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.62em]{3} \\ \hline
    $2 \times fact(1)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.62em]{4} \\ \hline
    $3 \times fact(2)$\\ \hline
    $4 \times fact(3)$\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 & 
 \begin{tabular}{ | l |}
    $fact(0) = 1$\tikzmark[xshift=0.62em]{5} \\ \hline
    $1 \times fact(0)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.7em]{6} \\ \hline
    $2 \times fact(1)$\\ \hline
    $3 \times fact(2)$\\ \hline
    $4 \times fact(3)$\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend right=50,-stealth]{f}{d}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend right=50,-stealth]{2}{1}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend right=50,-stealth]{4}{3}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend right=50,-stealth]{6}{5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\begin{tabular}[b]` for all 4 "inner" tabulars.

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work...

Comment: Ah, sorry this does work, I made a mistake when I tried it before and then made the same mistake again just now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just  use the  `[b]` option for each tabular. I took the opportunity to  put each `fact` in text mode, for a nicer layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][-3pt]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.5ex]\node[#1](#2){};}

\tikzset{brace/.style={decorate, decoration={brace}},
 brace mirrored/.style={decorate, decoration={brace,mirror}},
}

\newcounter{brace}
\setcounter{brace}{0}
\newcommand{\drawbrace}[3][brace]{%
 \refstepcounter{brace}
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[#1] (#2.center)--(#3.center)node[pos=0.5, name=brace-\thebrace]{};
}

\newcounter{arrow}
\setcounter{arrow}{0}
\newcommand{\drawcurvedarrow}[3][]{%
 \refstepcounter{arrow}
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw (#2.center)edge[#1]node[coordinate,pos=0.5, name=arrow-\thearrow]{}(#3.center);
}

\newcommand{\annote}[3][]{%
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[#1] at (#2) {#3};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \begin{tabular}[b]{ | l |}
    $3 \times \text{fact}(2)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.62em]{d} \\ \hline
    $4 \times \text{fact}(3)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.6em]{f}\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 &
 \begin{tabular}[b]{ | l |}
    $2 \times \text{fact}(1)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.62em]{1} \\ \hline
    $3 \times \text{fact}(2)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.6em]{2} \\ \hline
    $4 \times \text{fact}(3)$\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 &
 \begin{tabular}[b]{ | l |}
    $1 \times \text{fact}(0)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.62em]{3} \\ \hline
    $2 \times \text{fact}(1)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.62em]{4} \\ \hline
    $3 \times \text{fact}(2)$\\ \hline
    $4 \times \text{fact}(3)$\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 &
 \begin{tabular}[b]{ | l |}
    $\text{fact}(0) = 1$\tikzmark[xshift=0.62em]{5} \\ \hline
    $1 \times \text{fact}(0)$\tikzmark[xshift=0.7em]{6} \\ \hline
    $2 \times \text{fact}(1)$\\ \hline
    $3 \times \text{fact}(2)$\\ \hline
    $4 \times \text{fact}(3)$\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend right=50,-stealth]{f}{d}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend right=50,-stealth]{2}{1}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend right=50,-stealth]{4}{3}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend right=50,-stealth]{6}{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please let me know how to add a text next to the arrow?